# Suggestion for choice of database/design

Tags: database, database-design, search-engine, database-schema

Okay, i'm building a search engine based on `url`s stored in a database

`|  link_id  || link_url || link_tags|` <== schema

link_tags for a site say w3schools.com represent `[web-design,html,php,js]` etc..

and the database(MySql) has like 10,00,000+ rows

Now, i need them to be searchable by a search engine which also takes the `link_tags` into consideration while processing queries such as "best html tutorial" to return optimal results, also the entire web content of each url would also need to be stored to generate additional input to the engine based on keywords.
Which opensource search engine or any previous implementation should i be looking at to acheive this?

Comment: why the tag nosql when you are using mysql?

Comment: What are you planning to write the back-end in?

Comment: @James_Parsons php or python

Answer (score 0):

There is a small opensource search engine [here](http://www.sphider.eu/about.php/%22here). It is written in php and uses mysql. it my be able to be stretched for your needs.